# IF Function with multiple value and logic in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i've a little problem while using if function while using on google sheet and i'm not able to find solution.

i want to put every condition in function like

[image]

- A2 is positive and B2 is positive then C2 Will show Positive+
- if A2 is positive and B2 is negative then C2 will show Positive
- if A2 is negative and B2 is positive then C2 Will Show Negative
- If both A2 and B2 Negative then C2 will show negative+

i want to put all this condition on one formula or script which i can run on google app script

i've tried if function with AND, OR but wasn't able to solve.

Comment: You would get the same results just by testing A2 - the value of B2 makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IFS(AND(A2>0,B2>0),"Positive+",AND(A2>0,B2<0),"Positive",AND(A2<0,B2<0),"Negative+",AND(A2<0,B2>0),"Negative")
```